# AsyncTask HttpConnection in Android

Tags: android-asynctask

I want to create httpconnection using asyntask.three parameters are posted to the server
username,password and a search item.the search is provided by the user in an EditText such so that when the user clicks a button,the search item is sent to the server.I want to execute the doInbackground() method in the OnclickListener and display the response from the server on listviews.This is the AsyncTask Class

```
public class PostToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
     try {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
         String postURL = "url";
         String username ="username";
         String password = "password";

         HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", username));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", password));
             UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
             post.setEntity(ent);
             HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
             HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity(); 

             if (resEntity != null) {    
                 Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
             }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return null;    
}
```

This the class where the click event is called

```
public class StartPost extends Activity  {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.result_page);
}
    Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
     EditText textvalue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searcheditText);
     String value = textvalue.getText().toString();
     PostToServer post = new PostToServer();
     CheckInternetConnection check = new CheckInternetConnection(null);

 private OnClickListener click = new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(final View v) {
         switch(v.getId()){
             case R.id.btn_search:
                 post.execute();
                break;   
         }  
     }
 };
}
```

Questions
1.What am I doing wrong because it seems the post is not working and How can I display the server results from the onPostExecute()?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Create a onPostExecute method to display the results on your textview.

```
protected onPostExecute (String result){
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
   if(result != null){
      tv.setText(result);
   }
}
```